# How can I find out which driver/file is being loaded when the system hangs during the Windows 7 boot process?

Tags: windows-7

My desktop computer (1 OS, 1 drive, 1 partition) hangs during the Windows 7 boot process.  When selecting F8 I can select Safe Boot which allows me to see the files processed during the boot process.  I know that the last line displayed is the last file that was SUCCESFULLY loaded.  How do I find out what the next line, and the potential candidate driver/file/program would have been?

The unusual thing, at least in my experience, is that the freezing up of the system also happens when I boot from the Windows 7 install disks, which is preventing me from any repair options.

With a failure of both, I cannot not restore Windows 7 to a previous date or uninstall drivers/programs that may be the cause of the hanging.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to enable the **No GUI boot** option to get rid of the GUI during start-up. OS boot information shows a list of what's loading as it happens - during start-up - so you can know what file is loading if the system is frozen.

In the start search bar type `msconfig` to open **System Configuration**. Select **Boot** tab and tick the **No GUI boot** and **OS boot information**

[image: No GUI boot]

Comment: But he can't boot into windows in the first place...