# Windows 7 Loading speed

Tags: windows-7, performance

I have installed Windows 7 64-bit about two week ago. Since then everything was working alright, but yesterday Windows started to load much slower. Main delay comes while Windows logo is glowing -- it used to be around 10-15 seconds and now it's around 2 minutes.

As far as I remember, I have only installed Microsoft IntelliMouse driver recently and removed it today. Unfortunately I found out that I have switched off System Restore some time long ago, so can't even test if the problem can be fixed by restoring old version.

How can I troubleshoot the problem? Can I somehow find out what's causing the delay?

P.S. Please don't suggest to reinstall Windows. I know that will help, but reinstalling all software and settings is a pain and requires a lot of time.

**Edit:** I have also noticed that Windows Explorer is behaving strangely. It stopped showing icons for some files and folders and constantly hangs up (so that I have to restart it using Windows Task Manager).

**Edit:** Seems like the problem was that Windows went nuts completely -- slow loading was just the introduction. Later `explorer` started to hang up constantly, Skype conversation quality went totally bad. I couldn't even copy a file, since explorer was not working. I've reinstalled windows afterall.

Comment: do you have a wallpaper or a solid color only?

Comment: I have standard Windows 7 Wallpaper (bluish with Windows logo in the center, bird, butterfly, grass, tree etc.). I did change wallpaper only once about 2 weeks ago, but than returned back to default, since I didn't like any other. Does it have any influence on loading speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running the System file checker and see if it helps. Windows key + R, type "sfc /scannow" without the quotes, reboot.

Comment: Have performed the check. Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: In event viewer, go to Microsoft->Windows->Diagnostics-Performance->Operational and look for events with the 101 eventid. This might get you a lead.

Comment: While I wasn't able to determine the reason and just reinstalled the Windows, your advice may be useful for others, so marking this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling the **No GUI boot** and **OS information** to see what file is taking too much to load - see this answer how to do it: [How can I find out which driver/file is being loaded when the system hangs during the Windows 7 boot process?](https://superuser.com/questions/93727/how-can-i-find-out-which-driver-file-is-being-loaded-when-the-system-hangs-during/120643#120643)

You can also check the **Startup** and **Services** tabs since you are in the System Configuration to disable what you don't really need.

Comment: Tried it. It loads all libraries almost instantly, but there is big delay after last library loaded and before login screen appears

Comment: Second paragraph of your answer won't help, since I have delay in Windows loading speed, not user account loading speed