# Windows 7 hangs at boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze

Windows 7 64bit hangs during the logo screen. In the Safe Mode it hangs after the 
Loaded: \windows\system32\drivers\CLASSPNP.SYS and the ntbtlog.txt file isn't updated.

Is there any other way to get the list of the loaded drivers?

Comment: Have you looked the following question: http://superuser.com/questions/93727/how-can-i-find-out-which-driver-file-is-being-loaded-when-the-system-hangs-durin?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I tried these options. The result is the same as with Safe boot.

Comment: What about booting via the original DVD and performing a repair?

Comment: @Leonid - The instructions described in the answer to the question I linked to should have given you hints to which driver is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after BIOS updating.